# Implementing a custom overlay info window with GWT Maps

Tags: html, google-maps, gwt

I'm using GAE Java and GWT together on a website which is primarily a large map with basic infowindows.  I want to customize my info windows and I know how I want them to look-- but making this become a reality proving itself be tricky.  Here's what I want it to look like:

Whenever a marker is click, a new info window will appear a few pixels to the right of the marker.  The overlay will animate onto the screen, growing from nothing to about 300px by 300px.  This overlay will contain information injected from the GWT portion of the code and will have a button to close the div in the top right corner.

Writing this in plain JS or jQuery would be no problem for me, but what I'm having trouble deciding is how and where I should inject the div into the proper position ON THE MAP CANVAS?  Once i understand how I ought to do this, I believe i can finish the rest of the work myself.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

probably too late for an answer but for anyone else who'll end up here,
the following link should get you going
http://blog.mridey.com/2009/09/label-overlay-example-for-google-maps.html